# Air Android - Back button not working if keyboard is active

Tags: android, air, textfield

If you press the Android **back key** when the keyboard is active, the keyboard will disappear. On the second press the application closes but it should fired the *handleDeviceKeys* function.

This is my code:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleDeviceKeys, false, 0, true);

function handleDeviceKeys(event:KeyboardEvent):void {   
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK) {
    trace("fired")
        }
    }
```

Is there a fix for this?

(I'm using Flash CS6, Air 3.6 and tested it on Android 2.2 and Android 4 devices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listen stage: `stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN...`

If it will not work and you using StageText, then you must listen an instance of StageText instead.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This worked `stagetextinstance.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleDeviceKeys);
`